# From AppDelegate didreceiveremotenotification navigate to a certain viewcontrolller - swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have my TabBarController as my initial view (storyboard identity Main) (Class UITabBarController)
Then a NavigationController (storyboard id = ViewController) (Class UINavigationController).

Then my ViewController (storyboard id = View) (Class ViewController)

Then my Details (storyboard id = StoryDetails) (Class Details)

I would like to navigate from AppDelegate.swift to the Details.swift uiviewcontroller.

```
func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) { 
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let tabViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryDetails") as? UITabBarController {
            window!.rootViewController!.presentViewController(tabViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

But this is not working

Help would be really appreciated! (:

Also

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let detail = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryDetails") 
self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(detail, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code brings up the view, but there is no navigation controller or tab bar controller

Comment: What message did the console give you

Comment: The identifier would be `"StoryDetails"` not `"Details"` if everything you've included is correct.

Comment: Sorry, i changed the question, I had StoryDetails as the identifier.
It just loads the intial controller like normal,

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let detail = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryDetails") 
self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(detail, animated: true, completion: nil)

This code brings up the view, but there is no navigation controller or tab bar controller

Comment: I removed the if let, and checked print(tabviewcontroller) came up nil @Knight0fDragon

Comment: ..  when you go to present the view controller,  the console should give you a message explaining why it is failing,  if it doesn't, then I would check to see if window is not nil

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the window is nil, but I don't know why, i've tried :
as NavigationController = nil
as TabBarController = nil
as ViewController works, but i'm back at the initial page...

Comment: well 1st of all,  why are we doing this in the app delegate,  perhaps this is not the correct place to be doing this

Comment: @Knight0fDragon it has to be done in the app delegate because of the receiveremotenotification , as i'm receiving a payload from a push notification

Comment: that message could be received anyway where,  maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610896/controlling-which-view-controller-loads-after-receiving-a-push-notification-in-s

Comment: @Knight0fDragon , I got it working, thanks a lot, not sure if it's possible doing it the way I was but the link you gave me sorted it using the nsnotificationcenter.